# Incorrect address when service is hosted in Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

I have hosted a WCF service on Azure at http://voraservice.cloudapp.net/MyPushService.svc. The problem is when I connect through client, it gives me that no endpoint found at the given address:

`http://rd00155d3425e0/MyPushService.svc`

I dont know how this random servername came here and am trying to figure out since few hours how to remove this random server name and put the actual location of the WCF hosted on the cloud. Any pointers to solutions are appretiated!

**Update**: I saw this KB article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842/
But when I try to update for Win7 its says hte update is not for my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially I was redirected to this KB - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842/ but this dint help me on my Windows 7 machine.

Finally I was able to resolve this by adding useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress tag inside  serviceBehaviors tag.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ShoutboxWebRole.ShoutsBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        ...
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for this answer. I have been tearing what's left of my hair out over this same thing. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May sound like a manual instruction, but please check the config of consuming application. Often it is pointing to wrong direction. Here is a similar problem discussed in this blog post http://junooni.wordpress.com/tag/azure-incorrect-address-no-endpoint-listening/

All the best.